# cocos2d schedule selector outside class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, schedule

I want to schedule a @selector(count) interval: 1.0f to count the time left. 
here is my code: (In GameManager.m file)

```
-(void) count {
duration++;
[[[GameScene sharedScene] gadgetLayer] updateTimerLabel];
if (timeLimit - duration <= 5 && ticking == NO) {
    ticking = YES;
    [self schedule:@selector(untick) interval:5];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"tick.caf"];
}
if (duration >= timeLimit) {
    [self lose];
}
}
```

gadgetLayer is where i put timerLayer and scoreLayer stuff. 
the the count is not scheduled in GameManager.m, instead, i put it in my GameScene.m file:

```
-(void) onEnter {
[[GameManager sharedManager] schedule:@selector(count) interval:1.0];
[super onEnter
}


- (void)onExit {
[[GameManager sharedManager] unschedule:@selector(count)];
[super onExit];
}
```

But the timerLabel won't change. The count method is in GameManager.m file, does it have to be inside GameScene.m file? Anything wrong with it?

```
+(GameManager*) sharedManager {
if (instanceOfGameManager == nil) {
    return [[GameManager alloc] init];
}
else return instanceOfGameManager;
}


-(id) init {
if ((self = [super init])) {
    instanceOfGameManager = self;

    [self scheduleUpdate];
}
return self;
}`


-(void) update: (ccTime) delta {
    int a = 2;

}
```

`

i set a breakpoint in 'int a = 2' line, but can not be reached. 
[GameManager sharedManager] is called in appDidFinishLaunching method, so it won't be alloc'ed and init'ed again i guess.

Comment: Is your method count scheduled? Does the program reach this method ?

Comment: it reaches onEnter method of GameScene, without error, but won't reach count method in GameManager class

Comment: and i tried calling scheduleCount and unscheduleCount method of GameManager, scheduleCount is: [self schedule: @selector(count) interval: 1.0f] unscheduleCount is: [self unschedule: @selector(count)]; but the same result.

Comment: Did you check with debugger it does not reach or you just think it does not because you don't see what you want on the screen? Also from what class GameManager is inhereted ?

Comment: weird, i've tried scheduleUpdate in the init method of GameManager.m, and add a break point inside update:(ccTime) delta method, but it can not be reached

Comment: Inherited from CCLayer, as a singleton.

Comment: Please let me see your sharedManager method

Comment: Ive created a small project just for timer. could you send me an email? or leave yours if you don't mind?  thank you.

Comment: andrew.vorobev@gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I don't know why, but it work:

```
-(void) onEnter {
    GameManager *sharedManager = [GameManager sharedManager];
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(count)
                                          forTarget:sharedManager
                                           interval:1.0
                                             paused:NO];

//    [self schedule:@selector(tick:) interval:0.5];
}
```

Answering next question:

Unscheduling using sharedScheduler works perfect. Your problem is that you don't receive touch events because you've forgot `[super onEnter]` (and by the way `super onExit`) in HelloWorld.m and `super onEnter` is the place where CCLayer makes self registration with touchDispatcher. If you will add this everything will work.

Comment: hi, the @selector(count) won't stop when i push an PauseScene and call [GameManager sharedManager] unschedule...]method, sent you an email already. Thank you!

Comment: try using [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unschedule ...]

Comment: yeah, i tried that out, but still the same. Could you try that in my attachment? the second email. Thank you